# Create column from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create some new columns based on the value of a `dataframe` filed and a look up `dataframe` with some rates.

Having `df1` as

```
    zone    hh      hhind
0   14      112.0   3.4
1   15      5.0     4.4
2   16      0.0     1.0
```

and a  `look_up` df as

```
    ind     per1    per2    per3    per4
0   1.0     1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
24  3.4     0.145   0.233   0.165   0.457
34  4.4     0.060   0.114   0.075   0.751
```

how can i update `df1.hh1` by multiplying the `look_up.per1` based on `df1.hhind` and `lookup.ind`

```
    zone    hh      hhind  hh1
 0  14      112.0   3.4    16.240
 1  15      5.0     4.4    0.300
 2  16      0.0     1.0    0.000
```

at the moment im getting the result by merging the tables and the doing the arithmetic.

```
r = pd.merge(df1, look_up, left_on="hhind", right_on="ind")
r["hh1"] = r.hh *r.per1
```

i'd like to know if there is a more straight way to accomplish this by not merging the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You could first set *hhind* and *ind* as the index axis of `df1` and `look_up` dataframes respectively. Then, multiply corresponding elements in *hh* and *per1* element-wise.

Map these results to the column *hhind* and assign these to a new column later as shown:

```
mapper = df1.set_index('hhind')['hh'].mul(look_up.set_index('ind')['per1'])
df1.assign(hh1=df1['hhind'].map(mapper))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

another solution:

```
df1['hh1'] = (df1['hhind'].map(lambda x: look_up[look_up["ind"]==x]["per1"])) * df1['hh']
```